# Pass special characters to Maven Mojo Map key

Tags: xml, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, maven-mojo

I have the following property in my Maven MOJO plugin:

```java
@Mojo(name = "generate", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_SOURCES, threadSafe = true)
public class GraphQLCodegenMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    @Parameter
    private Map<String, String> customTypesMapping;
}
```

Which I usually set in the following way (based on the [Maven guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#mapping-maps)):

```xml
<customTypesMapping>
     <DateTime>java.util.Date</DateTime>
</customTypesMapping>
```

Now I want to allow plugin users to supply special characters as a map **key**.

I've tried different approaches, but neither of them work:

```xml
<customTypesMapping>
    <DateTime!>java.util.Date</DateTime!>
    <DateTime&#33;>java.util.Date</DateTime&#33;>
    <customTypeMapping>
        <name>DateTime</key>
        <value>java.util.Date</value>
    </customTypeMapping>
</customTypeMapping>
```

Is there a backward-compatible way to change my maven plugin (**not breaking existing clients**)?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `java.util.Properties`:

```java
@Mojo(name = "generate", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_SOURCES, threadSafe = true)
public class GraphQLCodegenMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    @Parameter
    private Properties customTypesMapping = new Properties();
```

In this way, it is possible to specify it in xml in 2 ways:

```xml
<customTypesMapping>
    <property>
        <!--note the special character below-->
        <name>Date!</name>
        <value>java.util.Date</value>
    </property>
</customTypesMapping>
```

and in a backwards-compatible way so that existing users of the plugin won't need to change their configuration:

```xml
<customTypesMapping>
    <DateTime>java.util.Date</DateTime>
</customTypesMapping>
```